# Position a div element next to a <rect> element inside a scrollable parent - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a scrollable parent div with dynamic `rect` element's inside. I want to position a `div` on the top of one of the rects.
I trying to do this:

**The HTML childElement:**

```
<rect x="401" y="2426" width="257" height="39"></rect> .
```

**The function to get the position:**

```
getElementCoordinates(element: HTMLElement) {
  const parentElement = this.documentContainer.nativeElement;
  return  - parentElement.offsetTop;
}
```

The `element.offsetTop` is `undefined`

**Then I try to position the `div`:**

```
elementPositionY = this.getElementCoordinates(document.getElementById(this.elelments[0]));
this.renderer.setStyle(this.clickToReleaseTooltip.nativeElement, 'top', elementPositionY + 'px');
```

How can I get the position of the rect and place according to this position the `div` ?

Comment: Please provide your full code and do not cherry pick it.

Comment: Even better, provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.